# Xamarin forms add page/view dynamically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, view, xamarin.forms

I was wondering if it would be possible to dynamically add a new page/view from the users perspective?

Right now I have a hamburger menu and I would like to be able to add a new page to it that uses a specific layout page.

Kinda of like how it is when you add a new page in a websites CMS.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes.  You can dynamically create a new ContentPage and navigate to it.

Comment: Oh Nice! Do you by any chance know how to do it? @Jason

Answer (score 7):

```
var page = new ContentPage();
page.Title = "My Page";
var content = new StackLayout();
// add content controls to layout here
// you could prompt the user for input - ie, how many buttons, or labels, etc
// and populate the stack accordingly
content.Children.Add(...);
page.Content = content;
```

you could also add a link to this new page in your menu's datasource so that it shows up in your menu

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense, but where and how does the new page get stored? @Jason

Comment: You can just keep a reference to it in memory, or try to serialize it's definition and store it on disk or in sqlite - it really depends on your requirements and architecture

Comment: Okey, right now I am using a REST service(Azure Hosted with Sql DB) that I created. The app is a todolist for a friend and he wanted to be able to add new pages each with a listview of different "Categories". @Jason

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a dynamic page for that.  Just have a single list page, and pass it a category string or id to filter on.

Comment: I know, it was just an idea to make each list alittle more clutterless ;) But how would I go about making the categories dynamic? Since he wants to be able to add new categories on the go? Sorry for so many questions. I am fairly new to appdevelopment... @Jason